# Why does my code throw java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, multithreading

I wonder why the following code throws `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException` when I lock `myInt`.

```java
package Thread;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MultiThreadingTest1 {

    public Integer myInt = 0;
    public Object lock = new Object();

    public void alternativePrinting() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() -> {
            while(myInt <= 100)
                synchronized (myInt){
                    if(myInt % 2 == 0) {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " prints " + myInt);
                        myInt++;
                        myInt.notify();
                    }
                    else
                        try {
                            myInt.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
        });
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(() -> {
            while(myInt <= 100)
                synchronized (myInt){
                    if(myInt % 2 == 1) {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " prints " + myInt);
                        myInt++;
                        myInt.notify();
                    }
                    else
                        try {
                            myInt.wait();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
        });
//        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
//        threadPool.submit(thread1);
//        threadPool.submit(thread2);
//        threadPool.shutdown();
        thread1.start();;
        thread2.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MultiThreadingTest1 multiThreadingTest1 = new MultiThreadingTest1();
        multiThreadingTest1.alternativePrinting();
    }
}
```

Execeptions:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at Thread.MultiThreadingTest1.lambda$alternativePrinting$0(MultiThreadingTest1.java:18)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at Thread.MultiThreadingTest1.lambda$alternativePrinting$1(MultiThreadingTest1.java:34)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

I know lock `lock` will be OK.
But I wonder why the following code throws `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException` when I lock `myInt`

Comment: You do `myInt++` followed by `myInt.notify()`. Think about what `myInt++` does. You end up with a _different object_. So, you're calling `notify()` on an object which you did not synchronize on, thus the error. But that's a symptom of a larger problem. Why are you synchronizing on `myInt`, a non-final field that is explicitly being reassigned, in the first place? Especially given you have that `lock` object (which should be `final`, by the way).

Comment: Why are you using wait and notify at all instead of proper Locks and Conditions, on an Integer object no less?